Homomorphism to a finite p-group/Lie ring Q: estimate on |Q|
Let $L$ be a finitely generated, torsion-free nilpotent group. Furthermore, assume it is also a Lie ring, i.e. a Lie algebra but over $\mathbb{Z}$. The correspondance between $L$ as a group and $L$ as a Lie ring is given by the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. Take a prime $p$ sufficiently large (at least larger than the nilpotency class of $L$). Each normal subgroup of index $p^k$ of $L$ is now also an ideal of $L$ as a Lie-ring with the same index. Group homomorphisms to $p$-groups are therefore also Lie-ring homomorphisms. I will formulate my problem in the Lie ring setting:
Let $w\in L$ be a designated vector, with $w \notin pL$. The vector is chosen such that for every Lie algebra $L_2$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ and every homomorphism $\psi: L/pL \to L_2$ with $\psi(w) \neq 0$ the rank of $L_2$ is at least $d$. Hence, $|L_2| \geq p^d$.
Now suppose $\varphi: L \to Q$ is a homomorphism with $|Q|=p^k$ and $\varphi(p^lw)\neq 0$. Is it true that $|Q| \geq p^{(l+1)d}$?
If $\varphi(w) \notin pQ$, then this holds. Indeed, let $L_3$ be a general Lie ring over $\mathbb{Z}$. We can define a Lie ring (over $\mathbb{F}_p$) on $p^iL_3/p^{i+1}L_3$ by using the bracket $[p^iv_1,p^iv_2] := p^i[v_1,v_2] \mod p^{i+1}L_3$. This way, we obtain a homomorphism of Lie rings over $\mathbb{F}_p$ of the form
$$\varphi_i: p^iL/p^{i+1}L \to  p^iQ/p^{i+1}Q.$$
Futhermore, multiplication by $p^i$ gives an isomorphism between $L/pL$ and $p^iL/p^{i+1}L$. Hence, we get for all $0\leq i \leq l$
$$w \in L/pL \mapsto p^iw \in p^iL/p^{i+1}L \mapsto 0 \neq \varphi(p^iw) \in p^iQ/p^{i+1}Q.$$
Therefore, $|p^iQ/p^{i+1}Q| \geq p^d$ and in conclusion $|Q| \geq p^{(l+1)d}$.
But what happens when $\varphi(w) \in pQ$? Can we for example make another homomorphism $\phi : L \to Q$ such that $\phi(w) \notin pQ$ (using that $w\notin pL$) and hence come to the same estimate?

I slightly reformulated the post to accomodate your comment. Hopefully, it is clearer for the reader now. @YCor
